# Garbled serial on custom Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, serial

I built my own [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno). I designed the schematic and laid out the PCB for a school project. I am having problems getting the serial communication to work so that I can program sketches. Here are pictures from Pin0 and Pin1 of the headers (Rx and Tx) when I send information using an Echo sketch. I programmed the sketch using the ICSP.

[image: Pin0]

[image: Pin1]

What can I do to fix my issue?

Below are screenshots of the code and the serial monitor before and after I send a message.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

When I took the pictures I sent a long random message so that I had time to freeze the scope.

Here is the schematic I made:

[image: Schematic]

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what the scope shots mean. What are the bytes you are actually sending? What bytes are you receiving on the receiver terminal? Can you post your code and your circuit schematics?

Comment: And what is the exact issue you are referring to? What do you expect to see, what do you consider wrong in the scope traces? Is your scope AC coupled by any chance?

Comment: That looks to me like the scope's ground isn't connected to the Arduino? Also, do you have it set to AC coupled by any chance?

Comment: First check the scope probe calibration...

Comment: @Ricardo I sent a random message so that I could freeze the scope. I think the requester of the images thought there might be noise or something on the line. Original post updated to include all the requested materials.

Comment: @jippie The scope is DC coupled. I have no idea what is wrong with the images. I posted them to my topic in the Arduino section and they told me to come here. All I know is that the echo coming back from the arduino is not what I sent.

Comment: @Majenko I don't remember if I connected the probe to ground or not. I will do it again and see if the results change.

Comment: Just now I got that you really made a Arduino Uno board. Did you load the correct firmware on the 16U2? That's who deals with serial comma in the board. In any case this is way over my head.

Comment: The code for the 16U2 is out there somewhere on the Arduino.cc site.

Comment: Also, is your probe on what pin exactly? Pins 29/30 on the 16U2, or pins 2/3 on the ATmega328P?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19270/discussion-between-user1362058-and-ricardo).

Comment: Funny that there seems to be a flip of one or two bits during the transmission. `r`, which is `0111 0010` in binary and `s` which is `0111 0011` both are received as `{` or `0111 1011`. Same for other characters.

Answer (score 1):

Through the chat we found out the problem. The Atmega16U2 did not have the fuses set to use the external clock. This was causing the 16U2 to divide the input baud rate by 8.

Thank you Connor for helping solve this problem.